# \chapter command in Devanagari

Tags: indic, hindi

I am writing a book in Hindi (Devanagari script). When I am using `\chapter`, it is not converting it in Hindi as अध्याय. I also tried `{\dn \chapter}` but it returns the title in English. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Nonetheless, by intuition I would say: try `\usepackage[hindi]{babel}` as in https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87wagner.pdf

Comment: The alleged duplicate is entirely unrelated as this question is about the word used for "Chapter" and that question is about an obsolete package... I don't see any connection between the two except the mention of the script (Devanagari). Could someone who voted to close explain why they thought the two questions are duplicates?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Error message came "Illegal character detected"

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following command in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).
This command re-defines Chapter as अध्याय.

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\dn अध्याय}
```

Comment: Not working. Error message came "Illegal character detected"